# The best way to use multiple large string lists in python

Tags: python, list, large-data

I got 6 lists of 100000 strings each, instead of declare them explicitly, I want to use something that is more efficient. Do anyone got an idea?

For exemple; I got a list of 20000 strings, and i want to browse it to find the one that looks the most like certain words chosen by the user.

Currently, I have something like :

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

myList = ["word1","example2"] #and so on up to 20000 words
bestRatio = 0
myWord = str(input("Chose a word to match"))
for i in range(len(myList)):
    newRatio = SequenceMatcher(a=myWord,b=myList[i]).ratio()
    if newRatio > bestRatio:
        bestRatio = newRatio
        matchWord = myList[i]
print(bestRatio)
print(matchWord)
```

But this thing, with 6 list of 10 000 words is, in my mind, not really efficient...

If you have any idea, post it, thank you :) !

Comment: Storing these large lists eats up a ton of RAM. You can store them in `csv` files and use `pandas`. If you're really concerned about performance, you can switch to other file formats such as `feather` or `hdf5` and use `Dask`(its similar to `pandas` but it can run tasks in parallel). If you'd rather avoid files, you can cache certain results using the built-in Cache module. This gives great run-time performance too. Here's a great tutorial on it
https://realpython.com/lru-cache-python/

Comment: What do you mean by "you can cache certain results"?

Comment: so lets say for example in a REST request such as GET/POST you requested data is "ABC". You check if the result for "ABC" is in the cache or not. If its not, then you do these calculations (in your case, run the loop.) Now before you send the result back to the client, store that result in the cache.
Next time if the same request comes in with "ABC" you wont have to run the loop. you can just return the cached result. This paragraph in explains it well
https://realpython.com/lru-cache-python/#caching-and-its-uses